# Adding empty row base on two columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of following structure

```py
x    y   z

93  122  787.185547
93  123  847.964905
93  124  908.932190
93  125  1054.865845
93  126  1109.340576
```

`x` `y` is coordinates,and I know their range.For example

```
x_range=np.arange(90,130)
y_range=np.arange(100,130)
```

`z` is measurement data

Now I want to insert missing points with `nan` value in `z`

so it looks like

```py
x    y   z

90  100  NaN 
90  101  NaN
...........................  
93  121  NaN                                    
93  122  787.185547
93  123  847.964905
93  124  908.932190
...........................
129 128  NaN
129 129  NaN
```

It can be done by a simple but stupid for loop.
But is there a simple way to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend use `itertools.product` follow by `merge`

```
import itertools
df=pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(x_range,y_range),columns=['x','y']).merge(df,how='left')
```